# pandas IndexSlice does not accept integer list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Using pandas IndexSlice, is it possible to use a list of integers?  I get KeyError: 'the label [xxxx] is not in the [columns]' when I use a list of integers (even when the values in the multiIndex level are formatted as strings):

```
vals = np.random.randn(4)
df = pd.DataFrame({'l1': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'B'], 'l2': ['9876', '6789', '5432',
    '1234'], 'l3': ['Y', 'X', 'Y', 'Y'], 'value': vals})
df.set_index(['l1', 'l2', 'l3'], inplace=True)

idx = pd.IndexSlice

# None of the following works
df.loc[idx[:, 6789, :]]
df.loc[idx[:, [6789, 1234], :]]

df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.l2 = df.l2.astype('str')
df.set_index(['l1', 'l2', 'l3'], inplace=True)
df.loc[idx[:, '6789', :]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters, your index columns are made up of strings, there's no chance of that working.

To slice out a single value, use the idiomatic `xs`:

```
df.xs('6789', level='l2')

          value
l1 l3          
B  X  -1.955361
```

For a list of values, specify an `axis` parameter to `loc`;

```
df.loc(axis=0)[idx[:, ['6789', '1234'], :]]

               value
l1 l2   l3          
B  6789 X  -1.955361
   1234 Y   0.703208
```

Note this also works identically to `xs` for a scalar;

```
df.loc(axis=0)[idx[:, '6789', :]]

               value
l1 l2   l3          
B  6789 X  -1.955361
```

Comment: `your index columns are made up of strings` - very good catch! :-)

Comment: @MaxU Must be the coffee I made today, has been quite helpful in keeping me awake :P

Comment: Edited above to my original list of integers, as that also was giving me an error.  Adding `(axis=0)` after `loc` is the key lesson, in addition to consistency between the dtype of the values in the index level and in the slicer.

Comment: @A.Slowey No problem. But for the purpose of this Q&A, better leave it as it is (otherwise your edit will invalidate MaxU's answer) :)

Comment: @coldspeed That's totally fair; your and MaxU's answers provide two alternatives and my previous comment emphasizes the most important parts, so that others understand everything they need to know to handle either case. I am curious, however, how `(axis=0)` and appending a `:` after the full `idx` expression achieves the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Alternative option:

```
In [76]: df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:, '6789', :], :]
Out[76]:
               value
l1 l2   l3
B  6789 X   1.306962
```

PS pay attention at string value `'6789'` and at the last `:` in the:

```
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[...], :] 
#  NOTE:     ---->         ^
```